# cycling between minibuffer and last window|buffer

Tags: buffers, window, minibuffer

I'd like to cycle between an active minibuffer window and the last recent buffer.

```
1  (defun cycle-to-minibuffer-window ()
2    (interactive)
3    (when (active-minibuffer-window)
4      (if (minibuffer-window-active-p (get-buffer-window))
5           (select-window (other-buffer (current-buffer)))
6        (select-window (active-minibuffer-window)))))
7  
8  (global-set-key (kbd "C-<f9>") #'cycle-to-minibuffer-window)
```

To bad that line 5 `(other-buffer (current-buffer))` returns, in this case, the wrong buffer. :(
**Which elisp construct could I use instead to get the buffer|window I wanted?**

*Example* (tested with `emacs -Q`):

1. There are 3 buffers: `*scratch*`, `*Messages*` and `*Minibuffer-0*`.
2. My active buffer is `*scratch*`. I do `find-file` aka `C-x C-f`.
3. Now pressing `C-<F9>` (calling my function), wants to switch to `*Messages*` buffer, but `*scratch*` buffer would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then the buffer you want is the value of variable `icicle-pre-minibuffer-buffer`.  It is the buffer that was current before the minibuffer became active."

If you don't use Icicles then you can save this buffer in a variable yourself by adding a function that sets it to `minibuffer-setup-hook`.  E.g.

```el
(defvar my-pre-minibuffer-buffer nil
  "Buffer that was current before the minibuffer became active.")

(defun my-save-pre-buffer ()
  "Set `my-pre-minibuffer-buffer'."
  (setq my-pre-minibuffer-buffer  (my-last-non-minibuffer-buffer)))

(defun my-last-non-minibuffer-buffer ()
  "Return the most recently used non-minibuffer live buffer."
  (catch 'my-last-non-minibuffer-buffer
    (dolist (buf  (buffer-list))
      (when (and (buffer-live-p buf)  (not (minibufferp buf)))
        (throw 'my-last-non-minibuffer-buffer buf)))
    nil))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'my-save-pre-buffer)
```

Having this buffer in a global variable means you can access it anytime. E.g.:

```
(with-current-buffer my-pre-minibuffer-buffer ...)
```

or

```
(pop-to-buffer my-pre-minibuffer-buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option I've found:

```
(nth 1 (buffer-list))
```

The minibuffer will be the 0th one in the `buffer-list` and the previous buffer is the 1st.

Comment: `(select-window (get-buffer-window (nth 1 (buffer-list))))` seems indeed to work

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which will only work if you use `ivy`, is to replace line 5 from my question with:

```
  (select-window (ivy--get-window ivy-last))
```